# tesseract is not recognising alphabets correctly in iOS

Tags: ios

I have to recognize the alphabets drawn on the screen. For this I am taking the Image of the alphabet drawn on the screen and passing it to tesseract. It's giving only 20% of results correctly. It's not recognizing all the characters correctly. How to train the tesseract to recognize the characters drawn on the screen correctly in iOS?

Thanks

Comment: Optical character recognition is very unreliable, even the good ones don't give 100% accuracy everytime. It isn't something that's dependable. Even a slight tilt in angle, different font, or lighting can produce erroneous results.

Answer (score 0):

Not only Tesseract, if you use any sdk you will not get the 100% accurate result. It mostly depend on the clarity of image, if your image is more clear then accuracy of output is high otherwise it is low.

Answer (score 0):

## Suggestion

Tesseract has very low accuracy. I really had a bad experience finding something that would recognize me text, image, etc, until [I found VUFORIA](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/getting-started-ios-native-sdk).

It is really a great software base on `OpenGL`and well documented, but has `non-ARC` it is a bit difficult to modify its classes, so you need to make some search.

Also here you can check a review what does it do: [Vuforia's Power](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IP5le6lZ_bw)